# Can you ask for user input for TFS 2015 CI build?

Tags: tfs, build, sonarqube, tfs-2015

This seems simple enough, but I can't find a solution for this online.

I am integrating SonarQube into our build definitions that get triggered on check in. I want the version SonarQube uses to be tied back to the project number defined by the business side of things.

Ideally, I would like to be able to prompt the user for input. When you go to check in and it kicks off the build, it would ask you for the project number to be used as the version for SonarQube. Is this something TFS 2015 supports?

Comment: Please add the "sonarqube" tag to get more attention with SonarQube related questions. Your question almost slipped the radar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this question is no, there is no way to prompt for input on a non-manually triggered CI build.

Here's what we did to work around this:
I wrote a Powershell script to read a config file and set the values to environment variables exposed to later build steps. Those variables are then what are specified in the Sonar Begin Analysis build task. I packaged that script up as a custom build task that will read a "sonar.config" file. This means all we have to do is add a "sonar.config" file to each solution we want to run Sonar analysis for, defining the key, name and version for the project, and then this build task will populate all necessary environment variables as the first step in the build.

So not a perfect solution, but it gets the job done without us having to add a lot of extra code to our solutions.

Answer (score 1):

### User input for build definitions

As far as I know, build definitions that are not manually triggered do not prompt for user input. A prompt allowing users to [set build variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables) is shown for manually triggered builds from the VSTS web page.

### SonarQube project version

I would recommend against you using the build or assembly version in your build tasks. This is because the SonarQube concept of version is quite different from the build concept. SonarQube uses versions as a [baselining mechanism / to determine the leak period](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak). If you up the version number often, the leak period is going to be too short to be actionable.

I'd recommend keeping the SonarQube project version in sync with your release schedule instead.

Comment: Yeah, keeping the SonarQube version separate form the build number is why I'm hoping to got the way of project numbers. It's just a matter of how to get that project number into the build in a convenient way that doesn't require someone to remember to go update the build definition each time a new project starts.

Comment: Where would read the project version from? You could read it in a powershell or cmd script and then create an env variable from it - build variables can access the env. But taking a step back here, I think SonarQube is focusing less on versions and more on leak periods - check out nemo projects https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=roslyn - the leak seems to be set to 30 days.

Comment: My hope was to be able to prompt the user on check-in for the project number. For our company, a set period doesn't make as much sense because a large number of our projects are sustainment or tech-debt cleanup projects, so a given product won't necessarily be under consistent development. But focusing the versioning around a project number gives us insight into how effective we were (especially operating on legacy code bases) over the duration of the project.